# load wcf hosts configurations from a different files

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, configurationmanager

My application is self-hosting several wcf services.
This creates quite a mess in the application configuration file and quite difficult to maintain.

I would like to find a way to separate those configurations, so that each wcf services will have it's own configuration file.

Thank you

**Edit:**
I've found a [way](http://www.mssoftwareconsulting.com/msswc/blog/post/Override-WCF-Client-Settings-From-Custom-Config-File.aspx) to specify a Client's config file, tried it, it works.
Now I just need to find how to do it for the self-host service, anyone?

Comment: Create an XML File or a dedicated host for each WCF service.

Comment: Thank you.
That much I know, my question was, how do I "tell" the service where his configuration file is.

Comment: Is this not what you are after? `var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration (path, ...);`

Comment: Pretty close.
I have found the complete answer.
I'm posting it now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer.
[This](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx) post includes the entire solution both on client and host side.
Thanks for those who answered.